# Error vs Meteor.Error

Tags: error-handling, meteor

What is the difference between `throw new Error` and using `Meteor.Error()`? Is it simply that `throw new Error` will not be shown to the client, only on the server (the client will get a 500 Internal server error); and `Meteor.Error` will be sent to the client.

Are there any more differences? E.g. Does one break out of Fibers, stops downstream code?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing with Meteor.Error is like you mentioned

- A full stack trace (may not be given by Error always)
- Possibility to send the error down to the client, in a limited non revealing form.
- Hide the error from the server in certain cases (if its thrown in a method or publish method, and from hooks such as `Accounts.onLoginAttempt`)
- The objects inside are EJSON serialised so a variety of data can be sent down to the client
- When a Meteor.Error is thrown, because of the EJSON serialisation you get a bit more information on the server side.
- Meteor displays the errors better.
  Often you can get `[Object object]` as the reason to be displayed from ordinary errors when they come from ordinary Errors, from `Meteor.wrapAsync`

Theres not much else that's different, `Meteor.Error` is a a subclass of `Error` with the above changes.

So they'll both stop downstream code. When it comes to Fibers, if the ordinary one is thrown out of a Fiber in any way its likely to stop your app (on the server side & not in a `method`, `startup`, `Meteor.setInterval`, `publish`, etc)

Its definition is also quite small: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/meteor/errors.js